# Drupal 8 - some child pages are not visible on particular book using view

Tags: views

I would like to ask for your help as I'm having a trouble in displaying some child pages of a particular Book in Drupal 8 using view. There's a book which displayed all the child pages but there's some book which displayed incomplete child pages and some book, doesn't display the child pages at all.

I created two views, one for the list of all top level book and the other one is for the child pages.

Here's what I have done on view settings:

**to display the list of book:**

```
Format: Unformatted list
Show: Fields
Filter Criteria: 
  Content Published (=Yes)
  Content: Content type (= Services)
  Book: Depth (= 1)
Sort Criteria: Content: Title (asc)
```

**to display the child pages:**

```
Format: Unformatted list
Show: Fields
Filter Criteria: Content Published (=Yes)
Sort Criteria: Content: Title (asc)
Contextual Filters: (Book Parent) Content: ID 
Relationships: Book Parent
Configure Relationship: Book Parent : Required this Relationship
```

After saving it, I added this to the block layout.

I'm not sure what went wrong on my settings.

Thank you in advance for you help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too experience in Drupal.  But normally I would not use Views for the child pages.  If the book module is enabled, the BOOK NAVIGATION block will be available to list with hierarchy like a table of content.  You can select in the option to display only for book pages under a particular book.  Not sure whether this helps.

Comment: The book navigation displays the child pages in dropdown format only. Am I right? Because what I would like to achieve is a customize layout for child pages. E.g. it should be in Grid format and the image, title, and body will also display. I think this will be doable using views.